# Facebook Account Kit change Font

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-account-kit

I noticed that account kit allows us to change the design, but only colors. On Chrome desktop with Account Kit Web the font that is appearing is TIMES, is there a way to customise the FONT on the ACCOUNT KIT pop up?